# How to verify a bank account detail is valid?

Tags: android, ios, api, banking

i am taking bank account details like account number and IFSC code as input. I want to know that any api is present to verify that the account is valid?

i have visited some websites but i don't feel that they are authentic?

Comment: I do not know for bank account and IFSC code but IBAN codes contains a checksum that can enable to verify the validity of the digit and letters. You could also the if there are some contant part like bank number , country code , … which are coherent.

Answer (score 1):

i am in this filed for a year now but still i am newbie and as long as i am here i don't think there is any API which gives this bank details for free or paid without banks permission so in my opinion you have to talk with bank for real bank info cause this is crucial info for which they can trade and can't make it public

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).